# いつの間にかVSCodeのPowerShellフォーマッタが動作しなくなってしまいました

Tags: vscode, powershell

##### 環境

Windows 10 Pro
VSCode 1.74.1

#### 症状

かつては動作していたと記憶しているのですが、いつの間にかVSCodeのPowerShellフォーマッタが動作しなくなってしまいました。

Shift+Alt+Fでフォーマットを要求するのですが、既にPowerShellの拡張機能「PowerShellv2022.12.1」が入っているにもかかわらず以下メッセージが出力されます。

```
'PowerShell'ファイルのフォーマッタがインストールされていません。
```

不思議なのは、このメッセージはVSCodeを立ち上げて最初のShift+Alt+Fの時だけ出力します。2回目以降なんどShift＋Alt＋Fを押しても何も起こりません。（空振りしている感じを受けます）
PowerShellの拡張機能を一度アンインストールし入れ直しても症状は改善できませんでした。どなたか見直しすべき所等ありましたら教えてください。

Comment: この Issue [Extensions being uninstalled on restart #168579](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168579) と同件かもしれませんね。まだ解決していないようですが。 取り敢えず前の1.73.1版 [October 2022 (version 1.73)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_73) にダウングレードしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご提案の通りダウングレードすると事象が改善しました。改善したあとVSCode 1.74.1へ戻すと、やはり事象も再現しました。どうやらkunifさんのご指摘の通りのようです。
しばらくversion 1.73を使っていこうとおもいます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

コメント指摘にて解決(というか回避)したようなので回答にしておきます。

こちらのIssueにもあるように、1.74.x版は拡張機能関連で不具合があるようです。
[Extensions being uninstalled on restart #168579](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168579)

上記Issueもまだ解決していないようなので、回避策として1.73.x版にダウングレードしてみると良いでしょう。
[October 2022 (version 1.73)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_73)

ダウングレードすることで元に戻って正常に動作するようになったとのこと。