# VSCodeでGolang実行時のエラー invalid option: ""exit status 1

Tags: go, vscode

以下のページを参考にAPIサーバーを作成しております。

[【Go】GinでREST APIを作ってみる(curlコマンドで動作確認)](https://zenn.dev/a_ichi1/articles/67b51de22475f9)

とりあえず、ディレクトリやコードなどを丸々コピーし、動作を検証しようと思ったのですが、
VSCode のターミナルで `go run main.go` を実行したところ、以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
 invalid option: ""exit status 1
```

調べても該当する情報が出てこないため困っているのですが、対処方法をご存じの方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

Comment: 参考サイトのどこまで進んでいるか分からないので現状のコード等を載せておいてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: VSCodeの版数は何でしょう？それによってはこちらの記事 [いつの間にかVSCodeのPowerShellフォーマッタが動作しなくなってしまいました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/92877/26370) と類似の現象かもしれません。